# What word describes putting oneself in reach of the law

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The title isn’t great and I couldn’t think of something more appropriate.

I'm looking for a work that can be used to indicate that the next phrase may put the writer at risk of being within the reach of the law.

The context might be something like:

> At the risk of {something} myself, I have to confess, I always steal the table sauce at restaurants

The word that came to mind was <strike>“inditing”</strike> “indicting” but searching for the meaning of the word, it seems to mean something different than I imagined.

Comment: [*indicting*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/indict)  means to accuse someone (including oneself) of a crime, usually formally, so I think it would cover your case. But I like Barrie England's choice better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Incriminating* might be the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about *exposing*?

Does it suit your purpose?

Comment: Thanks @Anixx - Exposing is certainly a valid synonym however "exposing myself" has other connotations that I'm happy to avoid :)

Answer (score 0):

To put oneself in jeopardy is to ***jeopardize*** oneself. Thus;

"At the risk of jeopardizing myself..."  or

"At the risk of placing myself in legal jeopardy..."